# Cross Browser Issue : document.getElementById().value not working in IE but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I have 1 dropdown box[year], 2 text box `[startDate, endDate]`, whenever user select year from dropdown menu then text boxes `startDate` should auto populate to `01/01/+year` and `endDate` to `12/31/+year`. Below mentioned script works fine in Firefox but in IE getElementById('ff5').value is not working, any suggestions ?

My script:

```
<script>
function autoPopulateDate(value, startDt,endDt){
      document.getElementById(startDt).value='01/01/'+value;
      document.getElementById(endDt).value='12/31/'+value;
}
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select onchange="autoPopulateDate(this.value,'ff5','ff6')" size="1" name="ff4" id="ff4"><option value="">--&gt;select value&lt;--</option><option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>

        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ><font class="rtabletext">Savings Start Date: </font></td>
    <td >
        <input type="text" value="" name="ff5" id="ff5" maxlength="50" size="10" class="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font class="rtabletext">Savings End Date: </font></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="ff6" id="ff6" maxlength="50" size="10" class="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yeah but IE is browser which I need to support.

Comment: @Rachel Works for me in IE (8).

Comment: I am using IE7, I do not have any other JavaScript page, actually this functionality is needed in Reporting Tool.

Comment: Works fine in IE 7. Is it possible you have some other element in your document with id or name "ff5"?

Comment: No I do not have other element with id or name as `ff5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE [at least some versions and rendering modes] wants you to access form members via the forms collection.

```
document.forms['someform'].elements['someelement'].value
```

Alternatively, you can use some ajax library (e.g. http://www.asp.net/ajax ) and use that libraries element retrieval method since those usually take browser compatibility stuff into account...

```
$get('element')
```

Comment: @KristoferA No, that's not necessary, the code works just fine. See @mu's fiddle, linked in his comment on the question.

Comment: +1, Strangely, it worked for me now if am trying to access using document.forms['someform'].elements['someelement'].value, thanks KristoferA

Comment: @Rachel nothing strange, just a browser compatibility quirk. It is possible (even likely) that later versions of IE have been aligned with other browsers. In other words, your original code may work in IE8/IE9 (when in standards mode) but not in IE7/6/5/4/3 or even new browsers if the page is rendered in quirks or compatibility mode.

Comment: @Pointy Can you clarify what portions of my answer you think are incorrect, and why?

Comment: @KristoferA the "document.getElementById()" method works perfectly well in Internet Explorer, back at least to IE 6 and almost certainly to IE 5 as well.