# How to select a value in a select dropdown with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

i have a drop down like this

```
<select style="width: 280px" id="Mobility" name="Mobility">
  <option selected="">Please Select</option>
  <option>K</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
</select>
```

I use this line to select a value it works in Mozilla not in IE? Why its not working?

```
var element = document.getElementById("Mobility");
element.value = "10";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [select <select> item by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324141/select-select-item-by-value)

Comment: How to do if there is no element ID? I have the name of element.

Comment: @RiponAlWasim you can use document.getElementsByName var element = document.getElementsByName("Mobility")[0];

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Use the [`selectedIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex):

```
document.getElementById("Mobility").selectedIndex = 12; //Option 10
```

**Alternate method:**

Loop through each value:

```
//Get select object
var objSelect = document.getElementById("Mobility");

//Set selected
setSelectedValue(objSelect, "10");

function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectObj.options[i].text== valueToSet) {
            selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there anyway without using selectedIndex?

Comment: How to do if I have the name of element instead of ID?

Answer (score 37):

easiest way is to just use this

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "banana";
```

myselect is name of your dropdown banana is just one of items in your dropdown list

Answer (score 15):

```
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) {
        if ( s.options[i].value == v ) {
            s.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Where s is the dropdown and v is the value

Comment: @GregM, based on the HTML in the OP this won't work. `s.options[i].value` should be `s.options[i].text`.

Comment: @GregM, The OP doesn't specify a value for the options, only text.

Comment: Ok yeah your right :(,  will let my answer there in case he puts some value ;)

Comment: it works in case he specify value in the options like `<option value="K">K</option>`

Answer (score 12):

The simplest possible solution if you know the value

```
document.querySelector('option[value=" + value +"]').selected = true
```

Answer (score 7):

I realize that this is an old question, but I'll post the solution for my use case, in case others run into the same situation I did when implementing [James Hill's answer (above)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140900/1843248).

I found this question while trying to solve the same issue.  [James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140900/1843248) got me 90% there.  However, for my use case, selecting the item from the dropdown also triggered an action on the page from dropdown's `onchange` event. [James' code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140900/1843248) as written did not trigger this event (at least in Firefox, which I was testing in).  As a result, I made the following minor change:

```
function setSelectedValue(object, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < object.options.length; i++) {
        if (object.options[i].text === value) {
            object.options[i].selected = true;
            object.onchange();
            return;
        }
    }

    // Throw exception if option `value` not found.
    var tag = object.nodeName;
    var str = "Option '" + value + "' not found";

    if (object.id != '') {
        str = str + " in //" + object.nodeName.toLowerCase()
              + "[@id='" + object.id + "']."
    }

    else if (object.name != '') {
        str = str + " in //" + object.nodeName.toLowerCase()
              + "[@name='" + object.name + "']."
    }

    else {
        str += "."
    }

    throw str;
}
```

Note the `object.onchange()` call, which I added to [the original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140900/1843248).  This calls the handler to make certain that the action on the page occurs.

## Edit

Added code to throw an exception if option `value` is not found; this is needed for my use case.

Answer (score 6):

Using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('drpSelectSourceLibrary').value = 'Seven';
```

Using Jquery:

```
$('select').prop('selectedIndex', 3); // This will select the 4th option from the dropdown list
```

Comment: Where did 'Seven' come from?

Answer (score 6):

**Using some ES6:**

Get the options first, filter the value based on the option and set the selected attribute to true.

```js
window.onload = () => {

  [...document.querySelector(`#Mobility`).options]
    .filter(x => x.value === "12")[0]
    .setAttribute('selected', true);

};
```

```html
<select style="width: 280px" id="Mobility" name="Mobility">
  <option selected disabled>Please Select</option>
  <option>K</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Note that in Typescript it actually needs to be `.setAttribute('selected', '');`, as the boolean type is not allowed here. This results correctly in `<option selected>`. See also [MDN setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#examples).

Answer (score 4):

[This may do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813123/cross-browser-issue-document-getelementbyid-value-not-working-in-ie-but-work)

`document.forms['someform'].elements['someelement'].value`

Comment: I definitely prefer James Hill's approach to this one but it still might be useful for someone

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As mentioned in the posts, `value` property is nonstandard and does not work with IE. You will need to use the `selectedIndex` property to achieve this. You can refer to the w3schools DOM reference to see the properties of HTML elements. The following link will give you the list of properties you can work with on the select element.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp

**Update**

This was not supported during 2011 on IE. As commented by finnTheHuman, it is supported at present.

Comment: and please take note of the date. This comment is written on 2011. I just tried .value on IE8 and it works fine. just an FYI. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) {
        if ( s.options[i].value == v ) {
            s.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I solved this problem by doing this

```
function setSelectedValue(dropDownList, valueToSet) {
    var option = dropDownList.firstChild;
    for (var i = 0; i < dropDownList.length; i++) {
        if (option.text.trim().toLowerCase() == valueToSet.trim().toLowerCase()) {
            option.selected = true;
            return;
        }
        option = option.nextElementSibling;
    }
}
```

If you work with strings, you should use the `.trim()` method, sometimes blank spaces can cause trouble and they are hard to detect in javascript debugging sessions.

`dropDownList.firstChild` will actually be your first `option` tag. Then, by doing `option.nextElementSibling` you can go to the next `option` tag, so the next choice in your dropdownlist element. If you want to get the number of `option` tags you can use `dropDownList.length` which I used in the for loop.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I made two significant improvements to the excellent alternative method, which was much better suited to my requirements, that was included in the accepted answer by @Janes Hill.

1. As written, the code in his answer matches against the display text of the combo box. I needed to match against the string specified in the value attribute of the option tag.
2. To allow for the possibility that the input value is missing from the list, I wanted to return the selectedIndex so that it can be tested, returning an invalid index when that happens.
3. As a matter of practice, I usually make all such evaluations case insensitive.

My improved function follows.

```js
    function SetSelectedValue ( selectObj, valueToSet )
    {
        const value2SetLC = valueToSet.toLowerCase();

        for ( var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++ )
        {
            if ( selectObj.options [ i ].value.toLowerCase ( ) === value2SetLC )
            {
                selectObj.options [ i ].selected = true;
                return i;
            }   // if ( selectObj.options [ i ].value.toLowerCase ( ) === value2SetLC )
        }   // for ( var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++ )

        return -1;  // Value not found
    }   // function SetSelectedValue
```