# Programmatically select dropdown option

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to fire option click programmatically with pure Javascript?

HTML:

```
<select id="racetype" class="select-menu" name="race-type">
            <option value="value" class="select-option js-select-option racetype-all" data-filter-value=".js-find-race-item">Race Types</option>
            <option value="value" class="select-option js-select-option racetype-sprint" data-filter-value=".js-type-sprint">Sprint</option>
            <option value="value" class="select-option js-select-option racetype-super" data-filter-value=".js-type-super">Super</option>
            <option value="value" class="select-option js-select-option racetype-beast" data-filter-value=".js-type-beast">Beast</option>
</select>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SOsprint();">Click to select the second option (Sprint)</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function SOsprint() {
    var select = document.getElementById("racetype");
    select.selectedIndex = 1;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140862/how-to-select-a-value-in-dropdown-javascript

Comment: hi dear check this url http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_option_index

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `[0]`. `getElementById()` returns just a single element and not a `NodeList`

Do this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("racetype");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `[0]` as [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns a reference to the element by its ID not an array.

Use

```
 var select = document.getElementById("racetype");
```

instead of

```
var select = document.getElementById("racetype")[0];
```