# Need JavaScript equivalent of jQuery changing the value of a dropdown when the value of a text field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, textfield, dropdownbox, formstack

I am working on a Formstack form.  I need to use Javascript to change the value of a dropdown box to whatever the value being typed into a text field is once a match is made.

```
<input type="text" id="field35497729" name="field35497729" size="50" value="" class="fsField">
<select id="field35497839" name="field35497839" size="1" class="fsField">
<option value="">&nbsp;</option>
<option value="CIPSmember">CIPSmember</option>
<option value="TECHCONNEXmember">TECHCONNEXmember</option>
<option value="TCBCpreferred">TCBCpreferred</option>
<option value="TCBCcomp2015">TCBCcomp2015</option>
</select>
```

So as soon as someone types in `CIPSmember` into the text field, the dropdown should be selected with the same value.  If there is no match, the dropdown has no selection.

I used the following jQuery on jsFiddle, but it is not working on Formstack:

```
$('#field35497729').keyup( function() {
$("#field35497839").val($('#field35497729').val()); 
}
);
```

Here is one Javascript method I am trying on jsFiddle that does not work:

```
document.getElementByID('field35497729').onkeyup = function() {
document.getElementById('field35497839').value = document.getElementByID('field35497729').value;
};
```

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140862/how-to-select-a-value-in-dropdown-javascript) and maybe 10 other places but I can't get it to work.  There are plenty of tutorials on how to get a text field to change when a dropdown selection change, but not nearly as many on the opposite.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive, just change your functions to `getElementById` and not `getElementByID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- misspelled ID in [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- missing end bracket on the jQuery version
- simplified to use this and $(this)

I am however curious. Perhaps you want an [autocomplete](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/) instead?

Here are your fixed versions

**Plain JS version**

```js
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('field35497729').onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById('field35497839').value = this.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field35497729" name="field35497729" size="50" value="" class="fsField">
<select id="field35497839" name="field35497839" size="1" class="fsField">
<option value="">&nbsp;</option>
<option value="CIPSmember">CIPSmember</option>
<option value="TECHCONNEXmember">TECHCONNEXmember</option>
<option value="TCBCpreferred">TCBCpreferred</option>
<option value="TCBCcomp2015">TCBCcomp2015</option>
</select>
```

---

**jQuery version**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field35497729').on("keyup",function() {
    $("#field35497839").val($(this).val()); // or (this.value)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field35497729" name="field35497729" size="50" value="" class="fsField">
    <select id="field35497839" name="field35497839" size="1" class="fsField">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="CIPSmember">CIPSmember</option>
    <option value="TECHCONNEXmember">TECHCONNEXmember</option>
    <option value="TCBCpreferred">TCBCpreferred</option>
    <option value="TCBCcomp2015">TCBCcomp2015</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do not even have enough rep for my vote up to count yet, but I do very much appreciate the answer.