# How can i select the respective value in a drop-down list from html according to name and id received?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can i select the respective value in a drop-down list from html according to name and id received?
i need it to edit this information from the data base

i'm trying with this code but don't show me the correct option that i want to send to the drop-down list

```
<select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" >
    <option value="true" >Available</option> 
    <option value="false" >Not available</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: When you say 'select' the value, how exactly do you want to select it? With PHP? .NET? Python? JavaScript? HTML has no ability to 'select' per se; it just displays content from the DOM. Considering you're using a database, regardless of the language, you need to put it in a `<form>` and `POST` the content to a back-end script. Alternatively, you need to extract the value in JavaScript and post the content to the back-end with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript for that. I don't think you can do it using html.
Update your question if you intend on using JS.

[How to select a value in dropdown javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140862/how-to-select-a-value-in-dropdown-javascript)

or like this

```
document.getElementById('status').value = 'true';​​​​​​​​​​
```