# Selected values dropdownlist value using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image]

I get these type of array in my javascript function as shown in image.Now i want selected all city in my dropdownlist which i get in my javascript array.
I have tried it but i didn't get success.How to do it.

```
function searchitem(id,name)
{
 var ADDRESS = value.Address;
 console.log(ADDRESS);
 $("#Address option[value='" + vin + "']").prop("selected", true);
}
```

HTML Code

```
<select class="ct-js-select ct-select-lg" multiple="multiple" id="Address" name="Address[]" style="margin-left:14px;">
    <option value="any">Any</option>
    <optgroup label="City">
    <?php foreach($Locations_Response->city as $CITIES){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo  $CITIES; ?>"><?php echo  $CITIES; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```

Comment: variable `vin` is undefined

Comment: you can use ADDRESS instead of vin

Comment: Is `ADDRESS` matching the value of `$CITIES`?

Comment: yes they both are matching

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140862/how-to-select-a-value-in-dropdown-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop:

```js
var ADDRESS = ['Aberdeen Twp.','2'];

$.each(ADDRESS,function(i,vin) {
       $("#Address option[value='" + vin + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="ct-js-select ct-select-lg" multiple="multiple" id="Address" name="Address[]" style="margin-left: 14px; " tabindex="-1"> 
<option value="any">Any</option>
<optgroup label="City"> 
  <option value="Aberdeen Twp.">Aberdeen Twp.</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: so what are you waiting for, post it here

Comment: $.each(ADDRESS, function( key, value ) {
           console.log(value);
          $("#Address option[value='" + value + "']").prop("selected", true);
        });

Comment: post the error man , the error, you know what a error is do you?

Comment: now there is no error occured,it's just syntax error

Comment: paste it here or fix it

Comment: i fixed the error now it doesn't show any error but the value is not selected in dropdownlist

Comment: paste the parsed html of the select here

Comment: <select class="ct-js-select ct-select-lg" multiple="multiple" id="Address" name="Address[]" style="margin-left:14px;">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        <optgroup label="City">
          <?php foreach($Locations_Response->city as $CITIES){ ?>
             <option value="<?php echo  $CITIES; ?>"><?php echo  $CITIES; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
        </optgroup> 
       </select>

Comment: @vinaykapoor by parsed i mean the code that is created after you execute the php

Comment: <select class="ct-js-select ct-select-lg" multiple="multiple" id="Address" name="Address[]" style="margin-left: 14px; display: none;" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        <optgroup label="City">
                       <option value="Aberdeen Twp.">Aberdeen Twp.</option>

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id='slc' name='slc'>
<?php
for($c=0;$c<10;$c++)
{
    echo"<option> ".$c." </option>";    
}
?>
```

script here

```
var txt=$('#slc').find(":selected").text();
```